# engage: cause to undergo interlocking, as of the components of a driving mechanism, such as a gear train

Tags: prepositions

> engage: cause to undergo interlocking, as **of** the components of a driving mechanism, such as a gear train

What's the meaning of 'of' here?

I saw the pattern of 'as of today' or 'as of now' but this is not that type of pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the phrase "as of". The words are separate. This is "as", roughly meaning, "for instance", and the normal preposition "of" which connects "engage" with "components".

So the definition means:

> engage: cause to undergo interlocking, **for instance, the interlocking of** the components of a driving mechanism, such as a gear train

Answer (score 1):

**As of** in a dictionary definition is their shorthand for 'when [the word] is used to refer to'.

So, when we are talking about gears or similar devices, *engage* has the meaning *cause to undergo interlocking.*

Comment: I think in 'as of today' equals 'as from today' but 'as from the components' does not make sense.

Comment: Why should it? As you said yourself, _as of today_ is a completely different expression, nothing to do with dictionaries.